# How to programatically list the relationship between two instances in an ontology?

Tags: routes, jena, ontology, instances

I have an ontology which i made up of relationship as follows

```
Company1 
  :hasSubsidary sub1 
  :hasDepartment Cars1 
  :hasSubdepartment Manufacturing 
  :isinBuilding  area1 
  :hasUnit PrecisionMaching 
  :hasMachine LatheMachine1
```

I have an ontology model with these individual created and relationships described.

Howe can I grammatically list all the relationship path given my input parameters are `Company1`, `Lathemachine1` using Jena or any other API?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what the namespace is for your ontology, so I'm going to speculate that it's `http://example.com/ontologies/test#`. Given that, you have two basic choices: to use SPARQL, or to use the Jena RDF API directly.

In the first case, your query is very simple:

```
prefix ex: <http://example.com/ontologies/test#>
select distinct ?relationship where { ex:Company1 ?relationship ex:LatheMchine1 }
```

You can see how to run a SPARQL query from your Java code [in the Jena documentation](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/app_api.html).

In the second case, it's also pretty straightforward:

```
Model m = ... your RDF model ... ;
String NS = "http://example.com/ontologies/test#";
Resource company1 = m.getResource( NS + "Company1" );
Resource lathe1 = m.getResource( NS + "LatheMachine1" );

Set<Property> relationships = new HashSet<Property>();
for (StmtIterator i = m.listStatements( company1, null, lathe1 ); i.hasNext();) {
  Statement s = i.next();
  relationships.add( s.getPredicate() );
}
```

**Update** after the poster explained the question more fully in the comments:

OK, so what you need is a path between the given nodes. If you only want *a* path, as opposed to *all* paths, you can use [`OntTools.findShortestPath()`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntTools.html#findShortestPath%28com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model,%20com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource,%20com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode,%20com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.Filter%29):

```
Path p = OntTools.findShortestPath( m, company1, lathe1, Filter.any() );
```

If you do want all paths, you could use the code in `findShortestPath` as a template for a simple breadth-first search.

Comment: Yes all are under same namespace but my problem is a bit complex than this.The relationships defined in the RDF file are as follows.The lathe and the company are not directly relate to each other. To put it more clearly Company1 :hasSubsidiary sub1 , sub1 hasDepartments Cars1, Cars1 isinBuilding area1,area1 hasUnit PrecisionMachning,PrecisionMachining hasmachine latheMachine1. I want to find out this whole route how company1 and latheMachine1 are related. Thanks for reply though I should have explained my question better.